# Does {-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK hide #-} have any effect on non-exported modules?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

Suppose I have a library packaged and built using Cabal, and some module `Internal` is not in my cabal file's `Exposed-modules`. Does it then make any difference if I specify a pragma

```
{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK hide #-}
```

at the top of `Internal.hs`, or is it already automatically hidden according to Haddock?

If it does make a difference, what effect does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does make a difference if the haddocks of the package are created with the `--internal` flag to `cabal haddock`.

```
$ cabal help haddock
Usage: cabal haddock [FLAGS]

Flags for haddock:
 -h --help                  Show this help text
 -v --verbose[=n]           Control verbosity (n is 0--3, default verbosity
                            level is 1)
  <snip>
    --executables           Run haddock for Executables targets
    --internal              Run haddock for internal modules and include all
                            symbols
  <snip>
```

If the haddocks are created without the `--internal` flag, the `hide` module attribute has no effect: no documentation is created for the module anyway.

If `--internal` is given, then documentation is created for non-exposed modules *except* those that specify the `hide` attribute.

In other words, documentation is generated if `hide` is not set *and* either `--internal` is specified or the module is exported.

The use of `--internal` for `cabal haddock` can be specified with `cabal install --haddock-internal`, or when manually invoking `cabal haddock`, or with the `runhaskell ./Setup.hs ...` interface.

Most people just run `cabal install` with the default options, so only few would observe the difference.

Comment: It's a `cabal` flag. I'll expand a bit.

Comment: I just did some fairly heavy editing of your answer, I hope that's okay. I also removed my now-irrelevant comment.

Comment: That's quite okay, it was an improvement. Thanks, @Ben.